# Python: dict multiplication

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra

I am using Python to learn linear algebra and I have two dictionaries:

```
v = {1: 1, 2: 8, 3: 0}
```

and

```
M = {(1, 2): 2, (3, 1): 1, (3, 3): 7, (2, 1): -1}
```

and I want to make a dictionary that adds all elements where the keys in v is the same as the first part of the tuples in M. Example of what I want as a answer for the two dictionaries here. (I will show the calculations I want to do)

```
newDict = {1: 1*M[(1, 2)], 2: 8*M[(2, 1)], 3: 0*M[(3, 1)]+0*M[(3, 3)]
```

which is the same as:

```
newDict = {1: 1*2, 2: 8*-1, 3: 0*1+3*7}
```

so I get a final dictionary in the form

```
newDict = {1:2, 2:-8, 3:0}
```

as you can see, I want the same keys as in the dictionary v. The closest I have gotten is this:

```
>>> [v[k]*M[r] for k in v for r in M if k == r[0]]
[2, -8]
```

Where I at least have the right answers, but I cannot get this to work. I don't know where to go from here or if I am at the right track at all. Sorry if my explanation might be lacking

Comment: It must be `3: 0*1 + 0*7`?

Comment: You are multiplying everything with that approach, right? You are not saying the "add together the multiplications" part.

Comment: Maybe you should have started to explain that you are trying to write multiplication of a sparse matrix and a sparse vector...

Comment: @hivert Yeah, thanks! English is not my first language, so I had difficulty doing that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are basing values on *multiple* input keys, use a loop, not a comprehension. Using a [`collections.defaultdict` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) makes the logic a little simpler too:

```
from collections import defaultdict

newDict = defaultdict(int)
for x, y in M:
    newDict[x] += M[x, y] * v.get(x, 0)
```

Output:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> v = {1: 1, 2: 8, 3: 0}
>>> M = {(1, 2): 2, (3, 1): 1, (3, 3): 7, (2, 1): -1}
>>> newDict = defaultdict(int)
>>> for x, y in M:
...     newDict[x] += M[x, y] * v.get(x, 0)
... 
>>> newDict
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 2, 2: -8, 3: 0})
```

Comment: I was writing exactly the same !

Comment: Blind typing on Dvorak layout FTW. :-)

Comment: Great answer, one little typo though. It should be `M[(x, y)]` instead of `y` or just iterate over `M.items()`. EDIT -- You fixed it, great! :D

Answer (score 1):

How about this..

```
newD = {k : 0 for k in v}
for k in v:
    for r in M:
        if k == r[0]: newD[k] += v[k]*M[r]
```

Comment: You still can use `dict.fromkeys(v, 0)` instead of the dict comprehension. Your code uses 3 loops (one nested) where just one loop would do.